# Cannot find reference 'Counter' in 'compat.py'

Tags: python, nltk, counter, compatibility

I am trying to run nltk's BLEU score calculation module that I got from [here](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/align/bleu.html). But am getting an error for the following import.

```
from nltk.compat import Counter
```

I tried a pip install of the Counter and it has been successfully installed. I have used the same interpreter for this project. But this is still shown as an error.

> Cannot find reference 'Counter' in 'compat.py'

I'm using Python 3.5 and working in pycharm.

[image]

Any suggestions in getting this resolved will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relation to your `nltk` version, the documentation you are following is outdated.

[There used to be `Counter` class](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/commit/67df2d6a3a55a19af7a001b4fdbff61773eb0b70#diff-46dba18d0b2c69a62ca8620b38ca4748L35) that is imported from `collections` inside `compat.py` and the `nltk.align.bleu` module was importing it as if it was defined inside `compat.py`.

Now there is no longer `nltk.align.bleu` but `nltk.translate.bleu` and you may want to use the [up-to-date documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.translate.html#module-nltk.translate.bleu_score) as well.

Just for completeness, `pip install Counter` will install the `Counter` [third party library](https://github.com/KelSolaar/Counter#usage) (than can then be imported as `counter.Counter`) that supports Python2 only and should be used only on Python2.6 and earlier now (if anyone still use those). It has been incorporated into the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) as `collections.Counter` since Python 2.7.

Comment: May I know where you got the reference code and documentation from? Recently (past 1-2) there's quite a lot of people using `nltk.align` which comes from out dated nltk version.

Comment: @alvas the reference code is from `nltk` repository on GitHub. This ( https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1145 ) is the specific pull request from 2015 where `nltk.align` module was removed and most of the functionality moved to `nltk.translate` module.

Comment: Ah, do you want to make the stack decoder work for the latest version of NLTK? Or just wanting to use the BLEU score =)

Comment: I am using Python 3.5 and hence I don't understand why it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Your nltk version is outdated. Please upgrade with.

```
pip install -U nltk
```

The current version should be 3.3. Version 3.0 is way too old.

Comment: It says that the `requirement is already up-to-date : nltk in ./my_project/lib/python3.5/site-packages (3.3)`

Comment: Is the Python you've `pip` installed is the same as the one you're using in `python`? `python -c "import nltk; print(nltk.__version__)"`

Answer (score 0):

Though my nltk version was up-to-date and I was using Python 3.5, I kept on getting the following error.

> Cannot find reference 'Counter' in 'compat.py'

It wasn't an ***issue*** with the `compat.py` file and instead a matter of ***not being able to resolve the Counter object***. Since the `Counter` is a dictionary subclass for counting hashable objects, I tried importing it using python's `collections` module.These are high performance container data types.This is available from Python 2.7.

So I simply modified the import statement as follows and it worked.

```
from collections import Counter
```

Just a few more [pointers on Counters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects): It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class is similar to bags or multi-sets in other languages.

Comment: Well I said: "There used to be `Counter` class that is imported from `collections` inside `compat.py`"